# Interesting Graph Theory "WOMVIES" problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Here is an interesting problem:
A graph is a set of vertices (points), some pairs of which are joined by an edge. For this problem, we will not allow an edge to join a
vertex to itself (i.e., no loops), nor will we consider pairs of vertices joined by more than one edge.
A subset S of vertices in a graph is called a womvie, (with one more vertex isolation ends), if
(1) no pair of vertices in S are joined by an edge, and
(2) the inclusion of any additional vertex in S destroys property (1).
For a graph G, M(G) will be used for the number of G's womvies.
[image: from C3 to Cn]

M(C3) = 3,

M(C4) = _____, What are the womvies?

M(C5) = 5 , What are the womvies??

M(C6) = _____ C6 has 2 womvie sizes.

M(Cn) = 7 what is n?

{1,3,5} is a womvie in which figures?

So Im not sure how to approach this problem. Its interesting, but i dont really understand the definition of a "womvie" Anything to help? The problem is really confusing with all the parts, but please edit to make it less confusing.
Thank you

Comment: Three things: 1) I don't see a question here?  2) the tags are probably not appropriate--maybe something more like graph-theory or discrete-mathematics.  3) It seems like a womvie is a maximal independent set.

Comment: @TravisJ Tried to fix 1 and 2. For 3, I'm not sure, it seems like it..

Comment: I see now that your questions are essentially "fill in the blanks."  A lot of "casual readers" may be put off by "fill in the blank" so you might want to edit that again.  (I'm not trying to be rude, just trying to help you ask a good question that gets a good answer.)  As for the "what is $n$" in the $C_{n}$ that will be a cycle on $n$ vertices (the other examples you gave are special cases with $n=3, 4,$ or $5$).

Comment: As long as you are only expected to count the number of WOMVIEs in a cyclic graph, it seems like it's pretty straightforward.  As far as I can tell, a WOMVIE of a cyclic graph is a subsequence of vertices, each of whom is separated from its predecessor and its successor by either one or two vertices.

Comment: @Brian Tung Im not sure I really understand, Could you explain in a solution?

Comment: @Elaqqad Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A *womvie* is a set of vertices such that there is no edges between any of this vertex.

For cycles that mean that if a vertex $i$ belongs to the *womvie* then neither $i-1$ nor $i+1$ belong to the *womvie*.

Moreover you have an additional condition for the *womvie* that say somehow that they are maximal. In other word you cannot add any vertex in a *womvie* and get a set that is a *womvie*.

For cycles that means that if a vertex $i$ **does not** belong to the *womvie* than either $i-1$ or $i+1$ belong to the *womvie*.

For $C_3$, if you take a set with more than 1 vertices you are sure that two of them are connected by an edge. Hence all the possible *womvie* are composed of at most 1 vertex. There are 3 different vertices hence 3 *womvie*

For $C_4$, for a set of one vertex $i$ you can add the vertex $i+2$ (the other side of the diagonal) and be sure that the vertex are not connected. Hence there is no *womvie* that have size 1 in $C_4$. If you take a set of 3 or more vertices you are sure to have two vertices connected by an edge. Hence there is no *womvie* that have size 3 or more in $C_4$. The only possibility left are set of size 2. Only the sets composed of the end of the diagonals are not connected by an edge hence $M(C_4)=2$ and the *womvie* are $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$.

I hope this clarify the definition of *womvie* and help you solve your problem.

ps:you can go through the other cases just as I did.

Comment: This sounds just like a maximal independent set.  Is this accurate?

Comment: @PaddlingGhost Yep exactly.